# Adding "jumpid" to HTML button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have spent the last few days searching for this answer with no luck at all. I am simply trying to add a tracking id to an HTML button.

Existing button

```
<a class="button" href="/home">This Button</a>
```

After "jumpid" has been added with jQuery.

```
<a jumpid="someValue" class="button" href="/home">This Button</a>
```

So far I've tried using "add", which doesn't work. I've also tried "append" and "HTML" which seems to only replace the button text for example...

```
<a class="button" href="/home">jumpid="someValue"</a>
```

I've also tried "insert before", and targeted the class.

```
$("jumpid=\"someValue\"").insertBefore(".button");
```

I wanted to also add that I am new to jQuery and if I haven't found the right documentation because I don't know the appropriate language please just let me know.

Comment: are there several different `jumpid`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `attr` in jQuery, below is an example...

```
$(function(){
    $('.button').attr('jumpid','test');
});
```

[Example fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/matty1491/wc8qunc6/). jQuery docs on [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is here for your reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: No worries @CarlSchoenleber, if you could mark this as the answer please, that would be great!